# Exception Handling with Stack in C++

Tags: c++

I have written a function for Stack where the function top() shows the top of the stack:

```
class RuntimeException{
    private:
    string errorMsg;
    public:
    RuntimeException(const string& err){errorMsg = err;}
    string getMessage() const {return errorMsg;}
    };

class StackEmpty : public RuntimeException{
public:
StackEmpty(const string& err) : RuntimeException(err){}
};

template <typename E >
const E& ArrayStack<E> ::top() const throw(StackEmpty)
{
    try{
        if(empty()) throw StackEmpty("Top of Empty Stack");
        return S[t];
        }
    catch(StackEmpty& se){
        cout << se.getMessage()<<"\n";
        }
    }


int main()
{
    ArrayStack <int> A;

    cout << "######\n";
    cout << A.top() << "\n";
        cout << "######\n";

    }
```

It shows below compilation warning:

```
$ g++ -Wall Stack.cpp -o Stack
Stack.cpp: In member function `const E& ArrayStack<E>::top() const [with E = int]':
Stack.cpp:91:   instantiated from here
Stack.cpp:61: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

The Output is:

```
$ ./Stack
######
Top of Empty Stack
6649957
######
```

Can someone tell what the warning is about and how to resolve it ? Also what does the the number '6649957' in output signifies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case `StackEmpty` is thrown, function doesn't return anything, though it is supposed to return `const E&`.

```
template <typename E >
const E& ArrayStack<E> ::top() const throw(StackEmpty)
{
    try{
        if(empty()) throw StackEmpty("Top of Empty Stack");
        return S[t];
        }
    catch(StackEmpty& se)
    {
        cout << se.getMessage()<<"\n";
        // Return operator is missing ! Possibly you want this:
        throw;
   }
}
```

**Edit.**
This is the way to use exception thrown from the method. You need to catch an exception in the client code, and not in the method itself.

```
template <typename E >
const E& ArrayStack<E> ::top() const throw(StackEmpty)
{
    if(empty()) throw StackEmpty("Top of Empty Stack");
    return S[t];
}

int main()
{
    ArrayStack <int> A;

    try
    {
        cout << "######\n";
        cout << A.top() << "\n";
        cout << "######\n";
    }
    catch(StackEmpty& se)
    {
        cout << se.getMessage()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally what should I return then because the stack is empty in this case. I tried catch(StackEmpty& se){
  cout << se.getMessage()<<"\n";
  return S[0];
  } which returns 0 as top of stack but the stack is empty.

Comment: catch(StackEmpty& se){
        cout << se.getMessage()<<"\n";
        // Return operator is missing ! Possibly you want this:
        throw;}
Did not work (core dumped)

Comment: What exactly did not work? Do you catch StackEmpty when top method is called?

Comment: My goal is not to use try and catch in main. I mean top() function should show the top of the stack and when the stack is empty it should show that. So ideally it should be handled in the function itself. Is there any mean to do so in top function itself?

Comment: You cannot return anything from the function if the stack is empty. The only thing I can think about is adding one element and return reference to it, but this is really stupid. Exceptions or returning error code is the common way to handle client code errors. Look, for example, for C++ Library containers, like std::vector.

Comment: If you want just to print the top element, make this function void, and print the element itself or "Stack is empty" message in the function.